# How do I add multiple fields that are in sync with my buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code works how I want it. However, I would like to have multiple fields added, and able to be edited when the buttons are pressed.

For example:

1. Add Property Button: Shows fields for Property_1_name, Property_1_address, Property_1_city etc. When the Add Property Button is pressed, it shows Property_2_name, Property_2_address, Property_2_city. Of course the Property number increases each time the button is pressed.
2. Edit Previous Property: This is where I run into problems. It works on a single field, but when I add multiple fields, it doesn't work. It does not maintain the data. I want to be able to edit multiple fields like I can with one.

Thanks in advance.

```js
var input, inputCount = 0;

function newInput() {
  $('#box > input').hide();
  inputCount++;
  input = $('<input data-id="'+inputCount+'"type="text" name="prop_'+inputCount+'_name" placeholder="Property '+inputCount+' Name">')

    .appendTo($('#box'));
}

function editPreviousEntry() {
  var cId = $('#box > input:visible').data('id');

  if (cId - 1 !== 0) {
    $('#box > input').hide();
    $('#box > input:nth-child(' + (cId - 1) + ')').show();
  }
  $('#box > input:nth-child(' + inputCount + ')').hide();
}

function editNextEntry() {
    var cId = $('#box > input:visible').data('id');

    if (cId + 1 <= inputCount) {
        $('#box > input').hide();
        $('#box > input:nth-child(' + (cId + 1) + ')').show();
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" onclick="newInput()">Add Entry</button>
<button id="edit" onclick="editPreviousEntry()">Edit Previous Entry</button>
<button id="edit" onclick="editNextEntry()">Edit NExt Entry</button>
<br/>

<br/><span id="box"></span>
<br/>
```

Comment: Where is your code for multiple fields, it looks the same from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30670978/how-do-i-create-a-button-that-allows-a-user-to-traverse-forward-through-recent-d/30671541#30671541

Comment: I haven't made the code yet, that is where I am stuck. that is just an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make it a div with inputs instead of a single input.

```js
var name, address, city, input, inputCount = 0;

function newInput() {
  $('#box > div').hide();
  inputCount++;
input=$('<div data-id="'+inputCount+'" id=input'+inputCount+'></div>').appendTo('#box');
  name= $('<input type="text" name="prop_'+inputCount+'_name" placeholder="Property '+inputCount+' Name">').appendTo(input);
address=$('<input type="text" name="prop_'+inputCount+'_address" placeholder="Property '+inputCount+' Address">').appendTo(input);
city=$('<input type="text" name="prop_'+inputCount+'_city" placeholder="Property '+inputCount+' City">').appendTo(input);
}

function editPreviousEntry() {
  var cId = $('#box > div:visible').data('id');

  if (cId - 1 !== 0) {
    $('#box > div').hide();
    $('#box > div:nth-child(' + (cId - 1) + ')').show();
  }
  $('#box > div:nth-child(' + inputCount + ')').hide();
}

function editNextEntry() {
    var cId = $('#box > div:visible').data('id');

    if (cId + 1 <= inputCount) {
        $('#box > div').hide();
        $('#box > div:nth-child(' + (cId + 1) + ')').show();
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" onclick="newInput()">Add Entry</button>
<button id="edit" onclick="editPreviousEntry()">Edit Previous Entry</button>
<button id="edit" onclick="editNextEntry()">Edit NExt Entry</button>
<br/>

<br/><span id="box"></span>
<br/>
```